# dplyr::summarise_all error after mutate_all

Tags: r, dplyr

Why does `dplyr::summarise_all` throw an error after `dplyr::mutate_all`?

```
mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate_all(scale) %>% dplyr::summarise_all(mean)
```

Either one of these alone seems to work fine, but it doesn't seem to summarise after the `mutate_all`.

```
mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate_all(scale)
mtcars %>% dplyr::summarise_all(mean)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scales` return a `matrix` with one column as output for each of the columns.

```
mtcars %>%
  dplyr::mutate_all(scale) %>%
  str
#'data.frame':  32 obs. of  11 variables:
#  $ mpg : num [1:32, 1] 0.151 0.151 0.45 0.217 -0.231 ... ####
#   ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 20.1
#   ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 6.03
#  ...
```

We can convert it to `vector` with `as.vector` or `c` and then apply `summarise_all`

```
mtcars %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_all(funs(as.vector(scale(.)))) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise_all(mean)
```